# Binary Operator Overloading C++

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I'm trying to overload the following operators to sort a string array using a Quick Sort or possibly Merge Sort algorithm. I'm have all my functions in a single class but I'm getting a "too many parameters for this operator function" error. Indeed, it will only accept one parameter. I looked up the problem and in a forum someone said that you can only use one parameter when overloading an operator inside a class. This doesn't make much sense to me. I'm trying to compare strings so I need the two parameters for the overloading. Am I supposed to overload the operators outside the class, and how would this work?

Here's my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Preprocessing
{

public:

void readFile(string list[], int size);
void quickSort(int list[], int lowerBound, int upperBound);
void swapItem(int &a, int &b);

//These are the overloading functions I'm trying to implement
bool operator<=(string a, string b);
bool operator<(string a, string b);
bool operator>(string a, string b);
};

void Preprocessing::readFile(string list[], int size)
{
ifstream myFile;
myFile.open("words.txt");

for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
{
    myFile >> list[i];
}

myFile.close();
}

void Preprocessing::quickSort(int list[], int lowerBound, int upperBound)
{
    int i, j, pivot;

    i = lowerBound;
    j = upperBound;

    pivot = list[(i + j) / 2];

    while (i <= j)
    {
        while(list[i] < pivot)
        {
            i = i + 1;
        }
        while (list[j] > pivot)
        {
            j = j - 1;
        }
        if (i <= j)
        {
            swapItem(list[i], list[j]);
            i = i + 1;
            j = j - 1;
        }//end if
    }//end outter while
    if (lowerBound < j)
    {
        quickSort(list, lowerBound, j);
    }
    if (i < upperBound)
    {
        quickSort(list, i, upperBound);
    }//end recursive if
}//end function

void Preprocessing::swapItem(int &a, int &b){
    int tmp;

    tmp = a;
    a = b;
    b = tmp;
}

bool Preprocessing::operator<=(string a, string b)
{
if (a.compare(b) > 0)
    return false;
else if (a.compare(b) == 0)
    return true;
else
    return true;
}

bool Preprocessing::operator<(string a, string b)
{
if (a.compare(b) > 0)
    return false;
else if (a.compare(b) == 0)
    return true;
else
    return true;
}

bool Preprocessing::operator>(string a, string b)
{
if (a.compare(b) > 0)
    return false;
else if (a.compare(b) == 0)
    return true;
else
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to replace the standard operators for comparing `std::string`? Or are you trying to make your type comparable to `std::string`?

Answer (score 5):

The signatures for the operators are incorrect:

```
bool operator<=(string a, string b);
bool operator<(string a, string b);
bool operator>(string a, string b);
```

1. When you overload an operator - and you implement it as a member function, it should only accept one argument (the other *thing* to compare to)
2. If non-member function (i.e. friend), then you can provide two arguments, however it cannot match an exiting operator (there is one already defined for `std::string`), and typically should accept your class as lhs and rhs for testing.

Comment: Oh, o.k. So then declaring the first parameter would be redundant then?

Comment: @rocklandcitizen - you got it.

Comment: @rocklandcitizen not redundant, unnecessary. The lefthand operand ("first parameter") is an instance of your class, accessible as the `this` pointer.

Answer (score 1):

An `operator` inside a class, whatever it is, has the special meaning of applying that operator to an instance of that class and optionally to parameters.

In your example the `operator<=` is supposed to compare an instance of the `Preprocessing` class with a `string`.

```
class Preprocessing
{
public:
    bool operator<=(string a);

private:
    string aStringField;
}
```

Typically you use `this` inside the operator method body to compare the instance with the parameter:

```
bool Preprocessing::operator<=(string a)
{
   return this->aStringField.length() <= a.length();
}
```

And you call it with:

```
Preprocessing p;
if ( p <= "a string" )
    // ...
```

Which is equivalent to:

```
Preprocessing p;
if ( p.operator<=("a string") )
    // ...
```

If you want to provide an operator that doesn't need the "point syntax" to be called, then you're looking for `friend` operators that exist outside your class.

```
class Preprocessing
    {
    public:
        friend ostream& operator<<(ostream&, const Preprocessing&);

    private:
        string aStringField;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It only takes one argument because the left hand side is passed as the `this` pointer.

Answer (score 0):

To overload an operator, the operator needs to be a method of the lefthand operand. C++ chooses functions (and operators) based on the types of the arguments (operands). Within a class, the lefthand operand is an instance of the class, available as the `this` pointer, so only the righthand operand may be specified as an argument to the operator.

In your example, you could do this:

```
class Preprocessing {
    public:
        bool operator<=(string b);
};
```

which would define a `<=` operator for comparing `Preprocessing` objects to strings. If you need to overload string comparison operators, you need to modify the `std::string` class, which is beyond my knowledge.